# Timeout when installing ruby gems

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm trying to install the **bundler** gem using `$ gem install bundler`. When I execute the command, I receive the following response:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
    Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation   timed out - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: bundler
```

In an effort to make sure I wasn't going crazy, I tried installing nokogiri:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'nokogiri' (>= 0), here is why:
  Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/latest_specs.4.8.gz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: nokogiri
```

And a2z:

```
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'a2z' (>= 0), here is why:
  Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - Errno::ETIMEDOUT: Operation timed out - connect(2) (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/a2z-0.1.3.gemspec.rz)
```

If anyone has experience this issue before and can help me out it would be greatly appreciated.

If it helps, I'm running **MacOS Mavericks** and have **gem version 2.2.2**.

Comment: This problem sucks.. I m getting it now

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your Gemfile set your

> `source 'http://production.s3.rubygems.org'`

This may not be an official answer, but it worked for me after three frustrating days trying to access rubygems.org.

Comment: This seemed to resolve itself after a day or two. I think there may have been a connection issue with their servers.

Comment: actually in my case it had been my fault - DNS pointed to an old address, which I had put in earlier to get around annother DNS problem

Comment: Can you give an example of what the full command line would look like? Do you put the source in front of the install command or after?

Comment: e.g `gem sources -a 'http://production.s3.rubygems.org'`. But this did not work for me.

Answer (score 21):

I resolved this issue disabling the IPv6 connections in my system OS.

It forces the OS just use the IPv4 and then it works.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. And since I had "Off" option missing in my Ethernet settings, I had to use CLI command `networksetup -setv6off Ethernet`

Comment: Thanks - had this strange and obscure problem too. Both answer and comment here helped a lot.

Comment: On Debian: `sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6=1; sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6=1`

Answer (score 9):

For people using Windows, the following worked for me on Windows 10. See also my [reply](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/2253#issuecomment-761777162) on the ruby gems issues list.

1. Go to **Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network connections**
2. Select the network connection you're currently using
3. Right click on it and choose **Properties**
4. Remove check mark for Internet Protocol version 6 (TCP/IPv6)
5. Click OK
6. Run your gem command again

Comment: Thank you for the comment explaining how to do this on Windows. This fix didn't work for me, as I ended up not having any internet (even though ipv4 was checked by default) so I had to unplug and replug my wifi usb stick and change it back to get internet

Answer (score 5):

i had the same issue which i solved by disabling my VPN.  try looking at proxies, VPNs, and other networking issues.

Answer (score 3):

api.rubygems.org is having issues with IPV6 host address. I faced the same issue after I setup the ubuntu server in vbox. We need to configure it to use our host's IPV4 first and then try IPV6.

So we can change the priority by adding this line ti /etc/gai.conf:

```
# Debian defaults.
precedence  ::1/128         50
precedence  ::/0            40
precedence  2002::/16       30
precedence  ::/96           20
precedence  ::ffff:0:0/96   10

# Low precedence for api.rubygems.org IPv6 addresses.
precedence  2a04:4e42::0/32  5
```

And it worked like a charm!

Answer (score 3):

1. `ping rubygems.org` and get the IP address.
2. Edit your `/etc/hosts` file and add the line:  `<IPADD> rubygems.org`.
3. `gem update --system`.

Answer (score 3):

For the people using macOS, the following worked me on macOS 12.3.1.

1. Go to **System Preferences > Network**
2. Click on the **Advanced...** button
3. Go to **TCP/IP** tab on the top
4. Change Configure IPv6 from `Automatically` to `Manually`
5. Click on the **OK**
6. Click on the **Apply**
7. Re-try installing your gems
8. Revert the changes back

Answer (score 2):

I encountered this just now. I needed to disable IPv6. I had to set mine to link-local only to get it to work. Otherwise, it's the same as @chootti's list:

1. Go to System Preferences > Network
2. Click on the Advanced... button
3. Go to TCP/IP tab on the top
4. Change Configure IPv6 from Automatically to **Link-local only**
5. Click on OK

Then I ran `sudo gem update --system` to update RubyGems. I still couldn't install gems with IPv6 enabled, so it looks like that needs to be off to install from RubyGems.

Machine this worked on:

> OS: MacOS Monterey 12.4
>
> Machine: Apple M1 (2020)
>
> Ruby install manager: ASDF

Answer (score 1):

just add --source http://rubygems.org to your installs. The issue most likely is with your internet connection.

Answer (score 1):

In my case helped the following:

```
sudo gem update --system
```

Comment: In my case even this is throwing a timeout issue

Comment: This is purely a Network and DNS config issue. I ran into the same thing, checked with a network which is not bound to any strict firewalls and auto-configured DNS, this worked. Looks like the source url of repo starts from https and not https, that maybe the cause. Just a guess, not sure.

Answer (score 1):

1. Disable ipv6
2. `sudo gem update --system`
3. `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 0):

dig api.rubygems.org +short

Adding below line to /etc/hosts worked for me:

```
151.101.192.70  rubygems.org
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue. Try running:

```
bundle pristine
```