# gem calls always timeout (can't reach rubygems.org)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, rubygems, timeout, bundler

I have a new install of Ubuntu 18.04.  I am trying to install everything I need for Ruby on Rails, but whenever I use the `gem` command I get a timeout error, like this:

```
chris@linuxbox:~/Sites$ gem install bundler
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'bundler' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

But if I paste that URL into my browser, I get the file right away!

Why can't I connect from the command line?

Comment: There is a proxy to bypass ?

Comment: @rfellons If there is, I don't know about it and don't know what to do to find out.  Any suggestions?

Comment: did you try this command in your terminal ? `gem sources -r https://rubygems.org -a http://rubygems.org`

Comment: @Vishal I had not.  I just tried it and got the same kind of error message -- timed out (http://api.rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)

Comment: Check whether you can download other things from terminal or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [gem cannot access rubygems.org](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org)