# I cannot install gems: Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, rubygems

### I cannot install gems

I was going to start a ruby ​​on rails project when this error occurred with the gems

---

- rvm 1.29.10 (latest) by Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin [https://rvm.io]
- ruby 2.7.1p83 (2020-03-31 revision a0c7c23c9c) [x86_64-linux]
- gem 3.1.2

---

##

```
renan@ZorinOS:~$ gem install rails
ERROR: Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - timed out (https://rubygems.org/specs.4.8.gz)
```

Comment: Your network or network settings are preventing access to rubygems.org. Check your firewall settings or contact your network administrator.

Comment: If you haven't solved it yet, have a look at this post
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49800432/gem-cannot-access-rubygems-org

Comment: @anothermh  https://rubygems.org/ is pretty unstable per se and happens to no respond or be quite laggy - at least in my recent experience

Comment: @shabunc "[Gems are hosted on Amazon S3, served by Fastly](https://rubygems.org/pages/about)", so no, I believe the problem to be at your end, not at the AWS or Fastly end.